# Stop Knockout from deleting the value of an input rendered in html

Tags: knockout.js

I have a fairly unique requirement where I want knockout to use the value attribute of an input tag as its default value when using applyBindings. At the moment when applyBindings is called it blanks out the value because the model contains no value.

Is it possible to somehow override applyBindings so that it uses the default input tag's value attribute as a default value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a custom binding to do this. Something like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.initFromInput = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        valueAccessor()(element.value);
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/SebBE/

You'll add this binding to any `input` element that you want to initialize from the HTML. Just make sure it's listed before the `value` binding so that the `value` binding doesn't update the `input` first.

```
<input value="input value" data-bind="initFromInput: v, value: v"/>
```

EDIT:

A better approach is to extend the `value` binding to use the `input` value based on the presence of an option.

```
var origValueInput = ko.bindingHandlers.value.init;
ko.bindingHandlers.value.init = function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
    if (allBindings.has('initValueFromInput'))
        valueAccessor()(element.value);
    origValueInput.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/SebBE/2/

This can be bound more simply and doesn't depend on the order of bindings.

```
<input value="input value" data-bind="value: v, initValueFromInput"/>
```

Comment: Probaly better to create a new binding or override the value binding.  Its fragile to have dependency to the order of bindings

Comment: @Anders, that's a good point. I'll update the answer with an example.